# How to handle plupload in expressjs using multer with chunking?

Tags: node.js, express, plupload

I am implementing a file upload using Plupload in the frontend and express nodejs in the backend with multer middleware for multipart/form upload. There is currently no example available, so this is what I got so far:

HTML frontend:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

    <ul id="filelist"></ul>
    <br />

    <div id="container">
        <a id="browse" href="javascript:;">[Browse...]</a>
        <a id="start-upload" href="javascript:;">[Start Upload]</a>
        <br />
        <pre id="console"></pre>
    </div>
    <script src="/plupload/js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
            browse_button: 'browse', // this can be an id of a DOM element or the DOM element itself
            url: '/upload'
        });
        uploader.init();

        uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
            var html = '';
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                html += '<li id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></li>';
            });
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += html;
        });
        uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
            document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
        });
        uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err) {
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
        });
        document.getElementById('start-upload').onclick = function() {
            uploader.start();
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

It basically just the plupload quickstart guide: http://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Getting-Started

Backend using node express. I trimmed my code down to a minimum working version for use here on SO:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

// Create express 
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.post('/upload', upload.array('file'), function(req, res){
  console.log(req.files);
})
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('App running...');
});
```

Basically, just a regular express app with multer package and serving static files.

**Question:**

How do I upload files using Plupload in the front-end and NodeJS (using express, multer) in the backend? It should also support chunking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fileFilter` function to validate your files before they are getting uploaded, this function enables you to validate filenames, extensions and which files should be uploaded and which should be skipped.

For, eg, Let's assume that you want the user to upload only "PDF" files, you can write a filter like this,

```
multer({
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (file.mimetype !== 'application/pdf') {
            req.fileValidationError = 'Only PDF files can be uploaded';
            return cb(null, false, new Error('Only PDF files can be uploaded'));
        }
        cb(null, true);
    }
});
```

Just in case if you want to restrict the user to upload files within certain MB, you can make use of the `limits` property which can be set as,

```
limits: { fileSize: the_file_size_which_you_want_to_allow }
```

And finally if you want to have a common file naming pattern in your destination directory (where the files gets uploaded) you can make use of the `fileName` function like this, (in the below example we are appending a hyphen and timestamp to the filename).

```
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can make use of the [plupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plupload) node module which will take care of the express-plupload communication which you're trying to sort out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: HI david, any idea how to let express "talk" to plupload?

Comment: @kosinix Yup, you can easily do that, Check my updated answer above (Under the **Update** heading)